# How to convert 2D array in to comma separated string in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Wanted to convert multi-dimensional array to comma separated string in `react.js`. 
E.g

```
   suggestionChips: Array(6)
   0: {identifier: "1", description: "One"}
   1: {identifier: "2", description: "Two"} `
```

Output should be in on comma separated string: `One , Two`

Comment: Please provide more details on the output format, and also show what have you tried.

Comment: Your example shows a one dimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (get an array of 'description' with `array.map`) and join it as a string ;

```js
var suggestionChips = [{identifier: "1", description: "One"}, {identifier: "2", description: "Two"}]
console.log(suggestionChips.map(e => e.description).join(', '))
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```js
let suggestionChips = [{identifier: "1", description: "One"},{identifier: "2", description: "Two"}];
let output = suggestionChips.map(chip => chip.description).join(', ')
console.log("Output", output);
```